# PHP include_once not showing pictures

Tags: php, include

I'm building my first site using php. I created a file called 'header.php' which contains my navigation and picture. On my 'index.php' I write inside the div where the header should be placed `<?php include_once 'inc/header.php'; ?>` now, you can see that the file is included but the pictures don't show and it looks like the div styles aren't working because the place holders for the pictures are in the wrong spot. If you look at 'header.php' by it's self in a browser everything looks fine, pictures are there with styles for containers. What am I missing here? This is my header.php file:

```
<style type="text/css">
@import url("../site_css/Css_reset.css");
@import url("../site_css/craig-smith.css");
</style>




<div class="picture"><img src="../graphics/header1.gif" />
        <div id="nav">

<table style="display: inline-table;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="400">
  <!-- fwtable fwsrc="navback_temp.png" fwpage="Page 1" fwbase="nav.jpg" fwstyle="Dreamweaver" fwdocid = "1996150392" fwnested="0" -->
  <tr>
    <td><img src="../graphics/nav/spacer.gif" width="80" height="1" border="0" alt="" /></td>
    <td><img src="../graphics/nav/spacer.gif" width="70" height="1" border="0" alt="" /></td>
    <td><img src="../graphics/nav/spacer.gif" width="134" height="1" border="0" alt="" /></td>
    <td><img src="../graphics/nav/spacer.gif" width="116" height="1" border="0" alt="" /></td>
    <td><img src="../graphics/nav/spacer.gif" width="1" height="1" border="0" alt="" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="javascript:;" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore();" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('nav_r1_c1','','../graphics/nav/nav_r1_c1_s2.jpg',1);"><img name="nav_r1_c1" src="../graphics/nav/nav_r1_c1.jpg" width="80" height="40" border="0" id="nav_r1_c1" alt="" /></a></td>
    <td><a href="javascript:;" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore();" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('nav_r1_c2','','../graphics/nav/nav_r1_c2_s2.jpg',1);"><img name="nav_r1_c2" src="../graphics/nav/nav_r1_c2.jpg" width="70" height="40" border="0" id="nav_r1_c2" alt="" /></a></td>
    <td><a href="javascript:;" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore();" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('nav_r1_c3','','../graphics/nav/nav_r1_c3_s2.jpg',1);"><img name="nav_r1_c3" src="../graphics/nav/nav_r1_c3.jpg" width="134" height="40" border="0" id="nav_r1_c3" alt="" /></a></td>
    <td><a href="javascript:;" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore();" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('nav_r1_c4','','../graphics/nav/nav_r1_c4_s2.jpg',1);"><img name="nav_r1_c4" src="../graphics/nav/nav_r1_c4.jpg" width="116" height="40" border="0" id="nav_r1_c4" alt="" /></a></td>
    <td><img src="../graphics/nav/spacer.gif" width="1" height="40" border="0" alt="" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and this is relevant info for index.php

```
<body>

<div id="body">
    <div id="header">
      <?php include_once 'inc/header.php'; ?>
        </div>
```

Comment: Try removing ../ on your paths

Comment: @sinisterfrog It looks like that is working put that in an answer

Comment: The url of the images should be relative to the index.php not header.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image paths need to be relative to index.php, not the include file.  You need to remove `../` from your `<img>` paths

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
<?php include_once './inc/header.php'; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Paths should be relative to index.php not header.php. Using dreamweaver to make changes to header.php you need to manually change paths because it will make everything relative to header.php.

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure the paths are correct? What does the file hierarchy look like?

Comment: files look like this: in public_html there is /graphics, /inc, and index.php. in /graphics there is /nav with the nav pics. in /inc is header.php

Comment: I'm pretty sure you shouldn't be referencing the includes with a leading '/'. This usually mean start from the root of the drive. Instead, you lead with the folder name and go from there.

Comment: The key difference here is an absolute path and a relative path. A leading / implies the former.

Comment: I don't have a '/' when I reference 'inc/header.php'

Comment: Oh weird, I thought I saw that. Another thing might be this part:

../site_css/Css_reset.css

The .. implies starting from the parent directory. If you're index file sits in the same folder as the site_css folder, you only need to do: @import url("site_css/Css_reset.css")

Comment: actually the import css doesn't need to be in the header.php file. I had it on the index.php but wasn't sure if it was taking effect

Comment: I think @Emco might have it. The url of the images should be relative to the index.php not header.php. It's as if you just copied and pasted the contents of the file into index.php, therefore everything is relative to it.